# Trouble Mounting a USB

Tags: usb, mount

I am trying to recover data from a USB for a colleague and am having a few issues. When I run dmesg I get the following

```
[  940.512202] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1094.509570] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1094.711296] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 1109.061122] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 1109.160277] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=1d00
[ 1109.160282] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1109.160285] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB DISK 30X            
[ 1109.160288] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer:                         
[ 1109.160290] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 1109.160646] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1109.161238] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[ 1110.192650] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB DISK 30X     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 1110.192971] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1110.196179] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

So I am assuming that it can be seen. However other utilities seem to indicate that the USB might be borked. For example the Disks program reports that there are no volumes on the USB and that it has no size and no contents :-/

Does any kindly soul have any suggestions please?

Comment: What are the outputs of `lsusb` and `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: @heemayl: don't use `fdisk -l` any more, use `parted --list` instead!  (drop by the AskUbuntu General chat room to discuss)

Comment: @Fabby: Good point..

Answer (score 1):

A USB disk is made up of two components: the control circuit and the memory circuit.

If you get connect/disconnect/connect/disconnect/... messages the control circuit is broken and the data can be recovered by unsoldering the memory chip and resoldering it onto another identical control circuit.

In your case, the memory chip is botched... (Your colleague should have received data errors before it ended up in this state, confirm with him/her/it)

So there is basically *one last thing* you can do: `ddrescue` the disk to an image, then run `testdisk` on the image... ***Do not run any mount/disk utilities, ...*** on that USB disk as you're only going to make things worse!

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.